# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (ColdFusion application)

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g

I have a ColdFusion 10 application with an Oracle 11g backend.

The Production version works fine.  Recently, I had the Oracle DBAs refresh the Test database from Production.   Now, I receive the `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` error.

All the tables are there when I use SQL*Plus and the queries run fine.   I am at a loss as to what to check now.  The trace sends me to the query that is running fine in SQL*Plus.   What have I missed?

Update - 17 October 2014
I don't know if it makes any difference, but the line throwing the code is the 1st one here:

```
`<cfquery name="getWebMaster" datasource="xxxxtest">
    select * from users where secureuserid in (select secureuserid from hd_role where  webmaster='Yes')
    and userstatus='Active' and UserLevel='XXX/XXIT'
</cfquery>`
```

That means that the entire cfquery section is the error, or just the 1st line?  BTW, I think I've figured out how to imbed code.  Thanx!

Comment: First thing I'd check is username application uses to connect to db. If it's not the same as the schema where all tables reside, all references to tables in queries have to include schema name (or all tables should have public synonyms, or first command after connection established should be `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=correct_schema_name` )

Comment: Nothing has changed except the data.  The two databases, and the code, were identical.  Thanx for the pointer.  I will attempt to figure it out.  Thank you

Comment: *when I use SQLPlus* 1) Are you using the same credentials used by the CF DSN? If not, test that first. 2) If it works, did you try deleting and recreating the CF DSN? *refresh the Test database from Production* 3) Exactly what was restored - the data only - or other objects too?

Comment: 1. Yes.  The datasource and the ID associated with it are the same.  In CF it isn't (and has never been) fully qualified (i.e.-xxxxTest.table) and worked fine.  In SQL*Plus if I am logged in as xxxxTest it doesn't require the full qualification; if Sys or whatever, then yes it does.   2) I will have to request that be done.  The gov't DBAS/SysAdmins have control of the code and database; I can only request changes.  3) They did a full dump via DataPump.  All the databases (Production, Test, Development) are identical in structure.  Thank you

Comment: Hmm.. I'm more of a SQL Server guy, but if it works with the same credentials, in SQL*Plus, it sounds like it should work in CF. I'm wondering if the `select *` has anything to do with it. Any change if you specify a few column names instead of `select *`?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one thing I can think of. The user that you used to run the application/script in your testing environment, and the permission that particular user has - it missed some privileges, so it can not see certain things even though they are there.

Comment: This happens when you bring up the application to login.

Comment: I've been messing with this since the 10th...  I was ensured by the DBAs that the datasource name is correct and the tables I am querying exist and are populated.  The one thing I've noticed is the directory structure that is spelled out in Application.cfc, for Production (which solved a previous problem) is now showing up and I can't get it to change to the Test directory structure.  The error is thrown on display of index.cfm and the Application.cfc isn't seen (that I know of) until later...  I am a very new CF person.  I'm sure that directory thing is the issue, but don't know how to fix it

Comment: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist   The source is set up and the tables exist when using SQL*Plus.