# <cfif isdefined("URL.openFile")> coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am severely new to ColdFusion... I have searched for help on this statement and have found a bunch of material, but still don't understand what is going on.  All of the parts of this statement make sense, but when I put them all together, it's confusing...  the ColdFusion 8: IsDefined("URL.variable) and is not"" thread is the closest, but I still don't understand.  This is the 1st statement in the index.cfm file of my application.   It's not throwing an error, I just want to understand how it works.  Thank you.

I have yet to be able to successfully post code here, so here is a [link to a text version of the index.cfm](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3594970/index.txt).

**Edit:** 
The code below should be the relevant sections related to URL.openFile

```
   <cfif isdefined("URL.openFile")> 
      <cfquery name="getFile" datasource="xxxxxxxx">
         SELECT filename, filename2, filecontent, filesize
         FROM Help_FooterInfo
         WHERE Help_id=5 and Section='Registration'
       </cfquery>
       <cfset sproot=#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#>
       <cfset newDest = #sproot#&"temp\">
       <cfoutput query="getFile">
          <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#getfile.FileName2#">
          <cfcontent type="application/msword" variable="#getfile.filecontent#">
       </cfoutput>
   </cfif>
   ...
   <cfquery name="getRegistration" datasource="xxxxxxxx">
      select * from help_footerinfo where help_id=5
   </cfquery>
   ....
   <cfoutput>#getRegistration.Content#</cfoutput><br>
   <a href="<cfif #getRegistration.filename2# neq "">index.cfm?openfile=Yes</cfif>" target="_blank">
       <u><cfoutput>#getRegistration.FileName#</cfoutput></u>
   </a>
```

The error message I am receiving (see comment below): [ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (ColdFusion application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304547/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-coldfusion-application)

Comment: You need to share some code, what is it doing vs what are you expecting it to do. Also, if you have `<cfparam name="url.openfile" default="">`, that will cause an IsDefined check to be true, even if no url parameter is provided. (That is the intended functionality of cfparam fwiw)

Comment: WHAT is the first statement in you index.cfm file? Put some code in there and we'll help you out :)

Comment: @LouieWarren - Without more details you are only going to get a generic answer.  What is it *specifically* you do not understand or find confusing? *RE: post code here* Try highlighting the code and using the code button `{}` in the toolbar. Also, when posting code try and omit code that is not relevant to the question asked. For example, the CSS code is not important here.

Comment: FYI: I added an abbreviated version of the code. It should include the sections related to URL.openfile. If not, feel free to [modify it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26408104/edit).

Comment: Thank you!  I am an Oracle DBA.  I have done some modification to CF code, but mostly know old html.  I inherited this application and am trying to understand it so I can better support it.  I am currently getting an error when this page is brought up.  The area throwing the error is between the head and body sections.  I just wanted to see what was happening prior to that.  To me, this is telling me if I get a valid URL continue?

Comment: @LouieWarren - If you mean the `cfif isdefined("URL.openFile")` part. That says, if the page is passed a url parameter named "openFile", then  run the code inside that block instead of displaying the login stuff. Nothing jumps out at me that would cause an error on page load. Can you edit the question to include the actual error message?

Comment: Thank you.  I can't find where openFile is assigned...

Comment: Can you post the full CF error message? The reason I ask is the query inside the cfif isdefined("URL.openFile") should NOT run when the page loads. Suggesting the error occurs with one of the other queries. But we would need to see the error message to know which one. Also, IF you know which table is causing the error - I assume you already verified it exists in the db? :)

Comment: *I can't find where openFile is assigned* It is created when you click on the hyperlink at the bottom of the page ie `index.cfm?openfile=Yes` - when the index.cfm page reloads. Whenever a CF script loads, the CF server automatically parses the url query string, in this case `?openfile=Yes`, and extracts any parameters. Those parameters are then stored in a system scope called `URL`. It happens automatically when that page reloads. That is why you cannot find an explicit assignment statement for the variable `URL.openFile`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've guessed at this stuff for years because my primary concern was database or help desk.  Now ColdFusion has been thrust upon me, this info is a great help.  I may eventually understand all of this!

Comment: No worries. We have all gone through something similar. I noticed you opened another thread for the db error. You should probably delete this one, since it's now a duplicate of the other.

Comment: This was for me to understand if anything prior to the DB error was causing something.  Not understanding what was there led me to post this.  They are related, but this is more for my education.  I can delete if neeed be.

Comment: Well if your original question was answered, just close out this thread. Though, do not depend on any of the comments being preserved. Those are considered temporary and can be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<cfif IsDefined("URL.variable") and URL.variable is not "" >
```

means, "If url.variable actually exists and is not an empty string".

A better alternative for `isDefined("URL.variable")` is `StructKeyExists(url,"variable")`.

Other alternatives for `is not ""` include `len(trim(url.variable)) gt 0`, and `isNumeric(url.variable)`.

Comment: +1 for explaining and giving some synonymous expressions to teach with. However, isNumeric isn't really synonymous and usually can't achieve the same goal. You may consider removing it and explaining that trim() removes whitespace.

Comment: Also, LEN(TRIM(url.variable)) is sufficient enough for a boolean comparison statement.

<cfif LEN(TRIM(url.variable))> Yay! <cfelse> Boo! </cfif>